# Looping through an array of arrays and removing an item

Tags: javascript, office-scripts

My question is quite odd because it's for OfficeScripts. I am pretty sure it is Javascript-based because that is what I have been writing in. Now onto my question. I have an array of arrays that I am backward looping through in order to remove some items. basically, I gathered row data from one table and then used it to filter other tables, and then built an array of an array using both data.
looking something like this:

```js
const Data = [["Name", "Area", "Position", "Shift"]];
const otherData = [["Training A","Course A","Level","Curricula"],["Training B","Course B","Level","Curricula"],["Training C","Course C","Level","Curricula"]];
var CombinedData = otherData.map(x=>[...Data[0], ...x]);
console.log(CombinedData);
```

What I am looking to accomplish is to remove the "Position" from every array in the CombinedData array of arrays. Right now I am writing this and it's emptying my array:

```js
const Data = [["Name", "Area", "Position", "Shift"]];
const otherData = [["Training A","Course A","Level","Curricula"],["Training B","Course B","Level","Curricula"],["Training C","Course C","Level","Curricula"]];
    var CombinedData = otherData.map(x=>[...Data[0], ...x]);
    console.log(CombinedData);
    
    for(let i = CombinedData.length -1; i>=0; i--){
      if(CombinedData[i][2] == Data[0][2]){
        CombinedData[i].splice(i,1);
          
      }
    }
    console.log(CombinedData);
```

What I would like the end output to look like is

```
CombinedData= [["Name", "Area", "Shift","Training A","Course A","Level","Curricula"],["Name", "Area", "Shift","Training B","Course B","Level","Curricula"],["Name", "Area", "Shift","Training C","Course C","Level","Curricula"]];
```

Which obviously isn't working. Any thoughts on what I need to do? JavaScript isn't my strongest language, and I am completely new to OfficeScripts. I appreciate any help.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any obvious relationship between `Data` and `otherData`, so it's very unclear if what your combination does is what you think it does.  Without knowing more about that relationship it's hard to help.

Comment: have you tried filtering the array before merging it? `var CombinedData = otherData.map(x=>[...Data[0].filter(e => e !== 'C'), ...x]);`

Comment: You're splicing at index `i`, which varies each time through the loop, while I think you want to splice at index `2` instead. Perhaps you should set a constant to determine or track where the index of `C` is.

Comment: I updated the info to be more relevant I was trying to be generic. Apologies if this made it harder to understand. @Tibrogargan.

Comment: It's no clearer, sorry.  You need to demonstrate what the output should be given the input provided.

Comment: Is that better @Tibrogargan ??

Comment: Yes, thanks.  That works

Comment: Just an FYI, Office Scripts uses TypeScript. TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. So all JavaScript code will work in Office Scripts, unless it's otherwise restricted.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianGonzalez that makes sense. Appreciate the info!

Comment: @EricScalise No problem. You can find more information on some of the limitations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/typescript-restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with `splice(i, 1)`, This should be `splice(2, 1)` since you need to remove the 2 (indexed) item.

```js
const Data = [["Name", "Area", "Position", "Shift",]];
const otherData = [["Training A","Course A","Level","Curricula"],["Training B","Course B","Level","Curricula"],["Training C","Course C","Level","Curricula"]];
    var CombinedData = otherData.map(x=>[...Data[0], ...x]);
    
    for(let i = CombinedData.length -1; i>=0; i--){
      if(CombinedData[i][2] == Data[0][2]){
        CombinedData[i].splice(2,1);
          
      }
    }
    console.log(CombinedData);
```

Comment: That was it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you only ever use element 0 of `Data`, just filter that once and use that in your combination:

```js
const Data = [["Name", "Area", "Position", "Shift",]];
const otherData = [["Training A","Course A","Level","Curricula"],["Training B","Course B","Level","Curricula"],["Training C","Course C","Level","Curricula"]];
var elem0 = Data[0].filter( y => y != "Position" )
var CombinedData = otherData.map(x=>[...elem0, ...x]);
console.log(CombinedData);
```